# how to plot and apply a function on a list

Tags: r

I am trying to get a plot and also optimise a parameter of a method.

here I load a package which I use and a related data

Then I make an empty matrix with 20 rows but unknown columns because I know I have less than 20 rows

```
output<-matrix(,20,)
```

here I want to apply the estimateBaseline function on $intenstity with different iterations number which I don't know how to do

```
iteration <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500) 

for (i in 1:length(fiedler2009subset)){
output[,i] <- estimateBaseline(fiedler2009subset[i], method="SNIP",iterations=100)
}
```

Comment: @Jimbou it is not a normal data structure , for example when I do the dput, I get something like this list(<S4 object of class structure("MassSpectrum", package = "MALDIquant")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("MassSpectrum", package = "MALDIquant")>, ......  That is why I am stuck in it

Comment: Use `estimateBaseline(fiedler2009subset[[i]], method="SNIP",iterations=100)`. See the help page and the examples section for more details `?estimateBaseline`

Comment: @Jimbou sorry I could not understand, I use it for dput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

```
output<-list()
for (i in 1:length(fiedler2009subset)){
  output[[i]] <- estimateBaseline(fiedler2009subset[[i]], method="SNIP", iterations=100)
  }
```

`output` is now a list. With lapply you can `loop` through each element:

```
lapply(output, head, 2)
[[1]]
         mass intensity
[1,] 1000.015      3149
[2,] 1000.117      3134

[[2]]
         mass intensity
[1,] 1000.015   3709.00
[2,] 1000.117   3701.75

[[3]]
         mass intensity
[1,] 1000.015      3834
[2,] 1000.117      3789
```

save it as a matrix/data.frame:

```
df <- do.call(cbind, output)
```

## Edit:

Upon you comment you can do something like this:

```
output<-list()
for (i in 1:length(fiedler2009subset)){
  tmp <- do.call(cbind, lapply(iteration, function(x) estimateBaseline(fiedler2009subset[[i]], method="SNIP", iterations= x)))
  # clean up 
  rownames(tmp) <- tmp[, 1]
  tmp <- tmp[, -seq(1, length(iteration)*2, by=2)]
  colnames(tmp) <- paste0(colnames(tmp), "_", iteration)
  output[[i]] <- tmp
  }
```

Comment: thanks I liked it already. is it possible to make the output same structure as its original data ?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I have no experience with `S4` objects. But why?

Comment: look at this post I did , I am stuck in it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390426/run-a-function-to-optimise-two-parameters-based-on-a-list-data-structure